# Как можно добавить View рядом с title в navigation bar?

Tags: swift, uikit

У меня есть `navigation bar` с `title` и с `view` в `rightBarButtonItem`. Как мне можно сделать так, что `view` было не в правом `item` `navigation bar'а`, а сразу справа от `title`?

Answer (score 0):

это можно сделать, используя кастомное вью для заголовка например такого вида, тогда `right view` на схеме как раз будет справа от также кастомного `title`, в этом случае для выравнивания заголовка не помешает добавить также и вью-заглушку слева (`left view`)

структура `myCustomTitleView`:

/----------------------------------
| left view | title | **right view** |
----------------------------------/

```
navigationItem.titleView = myCustomTitleView
```

Comment: А какое это должно кастомное вью для того, чтобы вместить текст и вью ?